# Getting ebean datasource configuration right with Play! 2

Tags: scala, configuration, playframework, ebean

Firstly, the relevant configuration that I've set in my current application.conf, which is actually pretty much defined in the [Java/Scala Ebean documentation from Play](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaEbean):

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.user="sa"
db.default.password=""
ebean.default="models.*"
```

I am running Play Framework 2.0.4

After poking around with Play, I wrote a couple of integration tests for my sample app. Found [this](http://digitalsanctum.com/2012/06/01/play-framework-2-tutorial-ebean-orm/) nice example on how to use Ebean to generate ddl code for my model and decided to give it a try but it seems that my Ebean configuration is missing something.

My code pretty much follows the example above, but it is Scala:

```
def setUp = {
    val server = Ebean.getServer("default")
    ...
    val ddl = new DdlGenerator(server.asInstaceOf[SpiEbeanServer], new H2Platform, config)
    ...
}
```

Calling `Ebean.getServer("default")` throws this exception:
`Could not create an instance of MyClassSpec  caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: DataSource user is null?`

Hm, maybe I got something wrong but I believed that the db.default.* properties had already set whatever Ebean needed.

I am too refering the same datasource name ("default") in both my application and Ebean and my test code is defined inside a `running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase("default")))` code block.

Is there anything more to configure? Thank you!

Comment: Try using `db.default.user=sa` (ie without the double quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I made it work with the ebean.properties file as described [here](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/getstarted_props.html).

```
datasource.default=default

datasource.default.username=sa  
datasource.default.password=  
datasource.default.databaseUrl=jdbc:h2:mem:tests;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1  
datasource.default.databaseDriver=org.h2.Driver  
datasource.default.minConnections=1  
datasource.default.maxConnections=25  
datasource.default.heartbeatsql=select 1  
datasource.default.isolationlevel=read_committed
```

So my database (ebean) related configuration is set in another file, with actually needing to be defined `ebeans.default="models.*"` in application.conf and `ebeanEnabled := true` in Build.scala

Hope it helps someone too!

Comment: Results in "In the map, path 'datasource.default' occurs as both the parent object of a value and as a value. Because Map has no defined ordering, this is a broken situation." for me.

Comment: For me, this problem was caused by `ebean.default="models.*"` line commented out in config, and setting username and password is unnecessarry for h2 — it works without these keys, tried.